# Issue while upgrading Timescaledb from 1.7.5 to 2.x

Tags: postgresql, docker, timescaledb

postgres=# ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;

ERROR:  function _timescaledb_internal.ping_data_node(name) does not exist.

I am performing an upgrade in a docker based setup with pg12 and timescaledb 1.7.5
I want to upgrade timescaledb to latest.
But facing above mentioned error.

Note: Dont want to lose data while performing upgradation.

Also If i tried specific version upgrade

ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE TO '2.0.2';
ERROR:  extension "timescaledb" has no update path from version "1.7.5" to version "2.0.2"

Tried running the command on -X flag.
Tried pg_dump and pg_restore respectively but facing issue as versions are incompatible.

Comment: Please, try to update to PG13 first, then move the version.

Also, depending how big is the service, it would worth to spin up a later version and use timescaledb-parallel-copy and you can get it much faster than jumping from version to version.